# Retrieve Number of Files with the name having same extension

Tags: java, collections, deserialization, fileinputstream, file-search

I have a folder User inside that i have so many files with same extension. 
I want to find all the user file name with a query that is filter.

In the following code how can i retrieve all the files which are equals to the query filter.

```
  public Collection<User> findUsers(String filter) {

     List<User> filteredList = new ArrayList<User>();
     try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( "Path of file" );
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();   

        while (object.equals(filter)) {
           filteredList.add((User)object);
           object = objectInputStream.readObject();
        }
        objectInputStream.close();
      }
      catch(Exception ioEx){
             //..............   
      }
   }
   return filteredList;
}
```

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your question. Are you trying to read the files in a folder or the objects in a serialized stream?

Comment: @chrylis : Yes I am trying to read the files in a folder and want to deserialized them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is small snippet to help you:

```
File folder = new File("/Users/you/folder/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    // Be aware that folder.listFiles() give list with directories and files
    if (file.isFile()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());

        // apply your filter. for simplicity I am equating the file names
        // name refers to input variable to method
        if(file.getName().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())) { 
            // create user object and add it to list. 
            // Change below line with appropriate constructor params
            filteredList.add(file.getName())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost helpful but not getting last line.

Comment: I am not sure what is User class in your application. I have simplified the answer to just use strings.

Comment: I have changed the condition to check for contains logic instead of equals, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :
get the file names

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Step 2 : store there names in some collection object
Step 3 : traverse the collection object and find any filter which you want

now , is your prob creating such filter ??

Comment: yes i can , but first i need a better explanation how you wanna compare , and then also your effort , what you have tried with your effort